# How can I supress a specific warning in a PowerShell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, scripting, warnings, azure-powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script that very often produces the same, irrelevant warnings. This warning pollutes the script output, and I want to get rid of it. However, I don't think it is a good practice to omit all warning, so I was wondering if it would be possible to omit very specific warnings?

In my case, I want to remove the following warnings:

> WARNING: TenantId 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' contains more
> than one active subscription. First one will be selected for further
> use. To select another subscription, use Set-AzContext.
>
> WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant
> 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' with error 'You must use
> multi-factor authentication to access tenant
> xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, please rerun 'Connect-AzAccount'
> with additional parameter '-TenantId
> xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.'

Any idea how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recommend that you use the most recent version of Az.Accounts to ensure that you are not facing any knowns issues (currently version 2.5.2).
When running `Connect-AzAccount` we populate the local context based on the first 25 subscriptions returned. It seems that one of those requires MFA therefore cannot get a token.
To avoid the warning, try to be specific of the subscription/tenant that you want to use.

Comment: Being specific about the tenant works to remove the second warning, which was happening when setting the context to a subscription via Set-AzContext. However, it does not work to set the specific tenant when using "Connect-AzAccount": the error persists. And I can't set the subscription because after connecting to the tenant I am iterating the tenant subscriptions. However, what I wanted to understand with my question is to understand if it is possible to ignore specific harmless warnings, like these ones.